# Rank strings based on integer value of adjacent cell?

Tags: excel, rank

My teacher has asked me to create a system in excel where she can enter test scores for various students, it will then calculate the total mark for all tests for each student. (Already done) My problem is that she also wants it to rank the students based on their scores.  Unfortunately I'm not what you'd call proficient with excel so I have no idea how to begin.
Please see image for better understanding

[screencap of what I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o33Nv.png)

Comment: Probably a good time to introduce you to Pivot Tables, as you can easily rank data that way.  You can sort by total score.  That would impress her.  You can do it in a formula.  You could also use a rank formula, but its much prettier to use a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

I did a pseudo mock up of your data.  I put the names starting in A3 and the total score in B3.

Then in M3 I put this:

```
=LARGE(B:B,ROW(1:1))
```

And copied down, to get the scores in order of the highest to the lowest.

Then using that as a reference I used this in L3:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$3:$B$28)/($B$3:$B$28=M3),COUNTIF($M$3:M3,M3)))
```

[image]